# Proof of that entire $A$ is a UFD iff every nonzero prime ideal contains a nonzero prime element. (Kaplansky)

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

This is called Kaplansky condition:
For $A$ entire, $A$ is a UFD iff every nonzero prime ideal contains a nonzero prime element.

Here prime element means that $p \in A$ is prime iff $p$ is non-zero non-unit and $p\mid ab$ implies $p \mid a$ or $p\mid b$.

Where can I get the proof of this statement?

Comment: you tried something?

Comment: noop... it seems this statement is a popular one, so I was expecting there is a kind of text-version proof of it

Comment: yeah that is alright to expect some text version but i suggest you to try on your own at least some part...

Comment: @julypraise You mean "An *integral domain* $A$ is a UFD iff every *nonzero* prime ideal contains a prime element." As for finding a proof, the first pdf hit of a simple google search [was this](http://sierra.nmsu.edu/morandi/oldwebpages/Math581Fall2012/Kaplansky.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

Kaplansky's book "Commutative Rings" has the appropriately correct statement in the first few pages.